# In Jvascript, How can I control to output of an array to have the number use only 2 decimal places?

Tags: javascript

```js
function tipCalc(bill) {
  var tipPercent;
  if (bill < 50 ) {
    tipPercent =  .20;

  } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200){
    tipPercent = .15;
  } else {
    tipPercent = .10;
  }

  return tipPercent * bill;
}


var bills = [124, 48, 268];
var tips = [tipCalc(bills[0]),
           tipCalc(bills[1]),
           tipCalc(bills[2])];
var finalValues =[bills[0] + tips[0],
                 bills[1] + tips[1],
                 bills[2] + tips[2]];
              
console.log(tips, finalValues);
```

I want 18.599999999999998 to display as $18.6 (in console.log). 
I tried using .toFixed(2) but had no success.

Comment: you want to add `$` with your result?

Comment: Yes I would like to add $ with result in console.log. In Example,  $18.6o

Answer (score 0):

Use `.toFixed(1)` to round values. [toFixed](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) is used to format a number with a specific number of digits to the right of the decimal. You might be returning the value directly using toFixed(). First save the .toFixed() value in a variable and then return that variable.

```js
function tipCalc(bill) {
var tipPercent;
  if (bill < 50 ) {
    tipPercent =  .20;

  } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200){
    tipPercent = .15;
  } else {
    tipPercent = .10;
  }
var val=(tipPercent * bill).toFixed(1);
  return parseFloat(val);
}


  var bills = [124, 48, 268];
  var tips = ["$"+tipCalc(bills[0]),
              "$"+tipCalc(bills[1]),
              "$"+tipCalc(bills[2])];
  var finalValues =["$"+ bills[0] + tips[0],
                    "$"+bills[1] + tips[1],
                    "$"+bills[2] + tips[2]];
                  
              
  console.log(tips, finalValues);
```

Comment: Thank you ellipsis. Do you know how I can get an answer with  $18.60. With the dollar sign in front.

Comment: I have made edits to the post, as you are entering the tips and calculating total manually i added $ manually, but for n elements you can do this using a loop too

Answer (score 0):

[`toFixed()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed) returns a `string` you need to convert it back to Number using [`Number()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number)

```js
function tipCalc(bill) {
var tipPercent;
  if (bill < 50 ) {
    tipPercent =  .20;

  } else if (bill >= 50 && bill < 200){
    tipPercent = .15;
  } else {
    tipPercent = .10;
  }

  return Number((tipPercent * bill).toFixed(1));
}


var bills = [124, 48, 268];
var tips = [tipCalc(bills[0]),
              tipCalc(bills[1]),
              tipCalc(bills[2])];
var finalValues =[bills[0] + tips[0],
                  bills[1] + tips[1],
                  bills[2] + tips[2]];
              
console.log(tips, finalValues);
```

Comment: Since it's not specified in the question consider this a note: [toFixed()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toFixed#Using_toFixed) will round up (>= .5) and round down (< .5).

Answer (score 0):

`.toFixed()` only works on number values, first convert `finalValues` to number and try

> console.log('$'+Number(finalValues).toFixed(2));

Hope it will help.